# Breeze SaveChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze, savechanges

I am new to BreezeJS, and have recently created a project that is up and running.  I am able to use Breeze to query data from my SQL server without a problem.  However, whenever I try to save changes, the changes do not save.  I have verified, in VS 2012, that the JavaScript save function is actually called, however the HttpPost method on the server side is never called.

Here is the Breeze Controller that I have set up:

```
    using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Breeze.WebApi;
using FitnessTracker.Models;

namespace FitnessTracker.Controllers
{
    [BreezeController]
    public class BreezeController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly EFContextProvider<FitnessTrackerContext> _fitnessContext =
            new EFContextProvider<FitnessTrackerContext>();
        //
        // GET: /Breeze/

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _fitnessContext.Metadata();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _fitnessContext.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<FitnessEquipment> FitnessEquipments()
        {
            return _fitnessContext.Context.FitnessEquipments;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the save function that I am using:

```
function saveChanges() {
        return manager.saveChanges()
            .fail(saveFailed);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="box-body form" data-bind="foreach: exercises">
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="text: EquipmentName" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g1" data-bind="text: EquipmentLevel" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="text: DurationSeconds" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="text: Weight" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g4" data-bind="text: DateTime" />
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

Save Changes

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Edit  9/12/2013:
I have fixed it thanks to Jay's help!!

The problem is that I was binding on the text instead of the value.  I changed the html to:

```
<div class="box-body form" data-bind="foreach: exercises">
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="value: EquipmentName" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g1" data-bind="value: EquipmentLevel" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="value: DurationSeconds" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g2" data-bind="value: Weight" />
    <input type="text" class="txt-m g4" data-bind="value: DateTime" />        
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

It is now saving without a problem.  Thanks Jay for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you confirmed that you are actually changing/or adding an entity within the EntityManager  on the client?  You can call the EntityManager's *hasChanges* method to confirm. Breeze does not attempt to call the server if there are no changes to save.

So try something like

```
if (manager.hasChanges()) {
   manager.saveChanges()
           .fail(saveFailed);
} else {
   // my guess is that you will get here.
}
```

My guess is that you either have a binding issue or have not queried or created an entity that  requires saving.

Comment: Jay, thanks, I now know what the problem is, I just need to find out what the root of the problem is.

I checked hasChanges(), and what do you know it is false (I was pretty certain that I had checked that already.)  I then added text boxes that were data bound to the same observables of my inputs.  When I made changes to my inputs, the values of the text boxes do not change.  I will now check to see why I am having this binding error.  Thanks.